# Currency converter with database reading from external files

Tags: windows, gml

I have a programming problem that I need to solve. I know how to do most of the things using separate applications like Excel to do the mathematical calculations or creating a Flash exe that will do a simple math conversion when a value is entered and a button clicked.
I am really not sure where to begin with bringing this together.
Requirements are a currency converter that will take a user entered value "weight" check which one of 4 precious metals they have chosen and multiply the two values by the relevant rate to display GBP. This new value is then multipled to to display USD and Euro values.
Once the user has completed a transaction I need to create a GUI that allows them to register and logs their transaction history, I would normally set up an Access database with a table of clients and transactions that are completed using a form. but bringing the two together in some sort of web based interface is beyond my abilities in terms of coding.
So not really sure where or how to get started. This is an educational project not commercial but any help or advice will be greatly appreciated.

Best regards
Cxtroen

Comment: The gml tag you are using is for the *Game Maker Language*.

Comment: Yes the gml tag is for Game Maker Language as that is the only IDE I have available to compile code. It is not suited to the task I have to accomplish but I nevertheless have to get this to work.